# Why does my python array list not follow order?

Tags: python, csv

I am having some trouble with python array list.

I know, that python list should keep its order, but I have script, where this is not true, and I cannot identify why, so I thought you might help me out.

There is little bit more complicated script, that is getting 2 lines from CSV file, take first line with weights, orders them, and than reorders the second line based on first one:

```
csv_cleared = csv.reader(open(temp_csv_file),  delimiter= ';')  
vahy = csv_cleared.next()
vahy_ordered = sorted(vahy, key=int, reverse=True) # orders line
vahy_ordered_indexes = []

for vaha in vahy:
    index_vahy = vahy_ordered.index(vaha)
    if index_vahy in vahy_ordered_indexes:     # if two mats have same weight
        index_vahy = index_vahy+1 # increment index by one
        vahy_ordered_indexes.append(index_vahy)
    else:
        vahy_ordered_indexes.append(index_vahy)
```

Log:

```
Vahy: ['49', '3', '19', '8', '19', '39', '11']
Vahy ordered: ['49', '39', '19', '19', '11', '8', '3']
Vaha is: 49 Index_vahy is: 0
Inserted index_vahy: 0 into vahy_ordered_indexes([0])
Vaha is: 3 Index_vahy is: 6
Inserted index_vahy: 6 into vahy_ordered_indexes([0, 6])
Vaha is: 19 Index_vahy is: 2
Inserted index_vahy: 2 into vahy_ordered_indexes([0, 6, 2])
Vaha is: 8 Index_vahy is: 5
Inserted index_vahy: 5 into vahy_ordered_indexes([0, 6, 2, 5])
Vaha is: 19 Index_vahy is: 2
Inserted index_vahy: 3 into vahy_ordered_indexes([0, 6, 2, 5, 3]) DOUBLED!!!
Vaha is: 39 Index_vahy is: 1
Inserted index_vahy: 1 into vahy_ordered_indexes([0, 6, 2, 5, 3, 1])
Vaha is: 11 Index_vahy is: 4
Inserted index_vahy: 4 into vahy_ordered_indexes([0, 6, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4])
```

This works as it should, but problem comes later:

```
new_line = line[:3]
line_materials = line[3:-1]
line_material = 0
for poradovnik in vahy_ordered_indexes:
    poradie = poradovnik + 3
    print "Poradie is: %s New line before insert is: %s"% (poradie, new_line)
    print "Inserting material: %s into position: %s" % (line_materials[line_material], poradie)
    new_line.insert(poradie, line_materials[line_material])
    print "New line after insert is: %s \n"% (new_line)
    line_material += 1
```

Where new_line.insert() function is inserting items with right indexes, but they keep having wrong positions, as shows log:

```
Poradie is: 3 New line before insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.']
Inserting material: TESCO 5K into position: 3
New line after insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K'] 

Poradie is: 9 New line before insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K']
Inserting material: TESCO expres into position: 9
New line after insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'TESCO expres'] 

Poradie is: 5 New line before insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'TESCO expres']
Inserting material: BILLA hlavny into position: 5
New line after insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny'] 

Poradie is: 8 New line before insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny']
Inserting material: Ptacek into position: 8
New line after insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny', 'Ptacek'] 

Poradie is: 6 New line before insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny', 'Ptacek']
Inserting material: Merkury Market SK into position: 6
New line after insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny', 'Merkury Market SK', 'Ptacek'] 

Poradie is: 4 New line before insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny', 'Merkury Market SK', 'Ptacek']
Inserting material: NAY elektrodom into position: 4
New line after insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'NAY elektrodom', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny', 'Merkury Market SK', 'Ptacek'] 

Poradie is: 7 New line before insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'NAY elektrodom', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny', 'Merkury Market SK', 'Ptacek']
Inserting material: TOP Farma into position: 7
New line after insert is: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'NAY elektrodom', 'TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny', 'TOP Farma', 'Merkury Market SK', 'Ptacek']
```

It seems like in some cases is item inserted into right position and other cases not, but I am stuck for few days already failing to find out when it is inserting into right position and when not

Comment: Reproduce the error in a smaller example. If you do that, you will almost certainly find the bug.

Comment: Besides @Anton's answer (which is correct), you also have the issue of what happens if you have more than two materials with the same weight. For example, suppose `'19'` appeared three or four times in `vahy`. Then what? One thing to remember is that Python makes it easy to create and work with tuples. Instead of separate lists of weights, indices, and materials, you could make a single list of (material, weight) tuples, sort by weight, and be done. (Or remove the weights at the end if needed.) Check [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) out for more ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anton said the problem is that you are inserting items outside the list bounds. There are many ways to solve this problem. This is a possible solution, keeping the original indexes in an ordered list of sets:

> ```
> vahy = ['49','3','19','8','19','39','11']
> indexed_vahy = [(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(vahy)]
> ordered_vahy = sorted(indexed_vahy, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
>
> new_line = ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.']
> line_materials = ['TESCO 5K','TESCO expres', 'BILLA hlavny', 'Ptacek', 'Merkury Market', 'NAY elektrodom', 'TOP Farma']
> output = new_line
>
> for index, weight in ordered_vahy:
>   output.apped(line_material[index])
> ```

And this would be the log:

> ```
> Vahy: ['49','3','19','8','19','39','11']
> Indexed vahy: [(0, '49'), (1, '3'), (2, '19'), (3, '8'), (4, '19'), (5, '39'), (6, '11')]
> Ordered vahy: [(0, '49'), (5, '39'), (2, '19'), (4, '19'), (6, '11'), (3, '8'), (1, '3')]
> Output: ['Kod regionu', 'Nazov regionu', 'Platova kat.', 'TESCO 5K', 'NAY elektrodom', 'BILLA hlavny', 'Merkury Market', 'TOP Farma', 'Ptacek', 'TESCO expres']
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can't insert item outside list bounds, so for example:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.insert(10, 10)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 10]
```

that `10` is inserted to position `3`, not `10`.